# Why was this answer deleted instead of commented?

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/18433/2776). The comment says it was closed for being unclear.

Two things:

1. To me it is perfectly clear. Surely, it could have been worded better, and perhaps added a bit of extra calculation, but the answer is overall correct.
2. If do not agree, then instead of delete, why not to ask for clarification rather than to close it? Seem a rather harsh decision. Even a downvote would have been better. If we apply such strict policy, a lot of answers here would be already deleted.

Comment: I was coming to meta to post about the same issue. Moderators, we appreciate your service, but this is something the community can decide on its own. Even if the case seems clear to you please think about deferring judgement.

Comment: @denesp Got it. I'll comment more employ moderation less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that this answer was deleted by a mod because it was originally just a single line of math (see https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/18433/revisions).*

The answer has since been edited with more detail and I have undeleted it.

---

*for what it's worth, I think an argument could be made that even that single line of math was an answer to the question as posed, although the added explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked at the modification history before asking (not that it would change the question though). I guess the OP writing the answer did not submit a request for reopening either.

Comment: @luchonacho Actually, there was a flag asking for reopening after the edit.

Comment: @luchonacho my bad. I'll be sure to comment more and employ moderation methods less.

Comment: @EconJohn well done for owning it, owning up to it, and learning from it. You'll become a great mod!

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I enjoy the site alot, I don't want to ruin it for others!

Comment: For what it's worth, I prefer my initial answer.